# Android: Drawing a line/border in toolbar layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the requirement that the appBar should look like this:

[image]

The background is simply transparent.

I use this layout to get an appBar (details hidden):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  <TextView>
  <ImageView>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Simply adding a view with `height=1dp` below the `ImageView` with `layout_gravity="bottom` won't work.

Is it even possible to draw a line or a border in the `ToolbarLayout`?

Comment: you can create an image like that and set it as backbround to toolbar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using RelativeLayout like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <RelativeLayout>
         <TextView>
         <ImageView>
         <View  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_menu"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Instead of `android:layout_below` I would recommend `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. That way you don't depend on any other views

Comment: This sadly doesn't draw the line to full width. There is still some margin or padding on the left introduced by the `Toolbar`.
If you set `HomeAsUpIndicator` (e.g. an image) this margin is even greater, because there is more margin/padding around this image.

Comment: @McOzD You can try this: app:contentInsetStart="0dp"

Comment: `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` didn't do it for me

Comment: You are not wrapping up the TextView and the ImageView. This is a compile time error! How do you plan this to work??????

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 this needs to be set to the toolbar

Answer (score 8):

Wrap the Toolbar in an AppBarLayout (which extends LinearLayout) and add the line as a view there:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        .../>

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="..."
          />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

With AppBarLayout there will be a default "key line" on Android 21 and up and I had to turn it off in code with:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    findViewById (R.id.app_bar).setOutlineProvider (null);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer but slightly modified. The desired line is added by the `AppBarLayout`, no need for the 1dp high view, unless you target anything lower than API 21 or want a custom line.

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution, by drawing to canvas:

```
class CustomToolbar(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : Toolbar(context, attrs) {

    private val lineColor: Int = Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)

    init {
        invalidate()
    }

    override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = lineColor
        paint.strokeWidth = 15f
        canvas?.drawLine(0f, height.toFloat(), width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), paint)
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```