# How to put color line on toolbar top and bottom

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to put color horizontal line top and bottom on the toolbar like given image below:-

[image]

In this image a green line is come from both side of toolbar.

I want to do same.

my layout xml :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="#F7F7F7" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks ..!!

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220252/android-drawing-a-line-border-in-toolbar-layout

Comment: just provide "two green lines" background `Drawable` (`setBackground` method or `android:background` property)

Answer (score 5):

Implement your layout like following

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F7F7F7"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create Custom layout like below sample code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/dl_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/green"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its not take full width toolbar leave some space of left side.

Answer (score 0):

AppBarLayout extends from LinearLayout, so you can use AppBarLayout as LinearLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="#F7F7F7" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```